# CentOS 6.4 - Cant get an IP from DHCP

Tags: centos, iptables, dhcp

I have a Ubuntu and CentOS system running on XenServer. The Ubuntu Box gets and IP from DHCP no problem. The CentOS will not take a DHCP but a static address works fine.

```
[root@XenCentOS ~]# service network restart
Shutting down interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  
Determining IP information for eth0... failed.
[FAILED]
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file

```
DEVICE=eth0                                                                     
BOOTPROTO=dhcp                                                                  
HWADDR=5A:3C:1C:48:C2:6C                                                        
ONBOOT=yes
```

I added an iptables rule for DHCP, but this didnt appear to work so I turned off iptables. Any idea what can cause this ?

Also dmesg has some intresting items

```
Initialising Xen virtual ethernet driver.
alloc irq_desc for 274 on node 0
alloc kstat_irqs on node 0
alloc irq_desc for 273 on node 0
alloc kstat_irqs on node 0
NET: Registered protocol family 10
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Comment: Does it get an address if you just run `dhclient eth0`?

Comment: @Shane Madden no sir, also it appears to hang with that command.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe run a `tcpdump` to watch what's going on when it's attempting to get an address?

Comment: You could also try `dhcping` and/or `dhcpdump` to diagnose the problem.